# How to submit a form from any controller - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to put a simple email signup form in the footer of every page of my website. So I created a subscription scaffold and have made the following partial:

```
<%= form_for @subscription, :url => {:controller => 'subscriptions', :action => 'create'} do |f| %>
 <div class="input-append">
   <%= f.text_field(:email, :id => "appendedInputButton", :placeholder => 'Subscribe', :class => 'span4') %><button class="btn" type="submit" name="commit">Subscribe</button>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

But despite specifying the controller and action I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

The form works fine from the subscriptions/new page but how do I make it so I can submit the form from any controller and any page without having to define @subscription everywhere?

Comment: makes no difference, same error

Comment: did you use scaffold to generate Subscription?

Comment: yes I did rails g scaffold subscription email:string first_name:string

Comment: I dont think you need :url part. <%= form_for(@subscription) do |f| %> should be enough.

Comment: no that doesnt work, other pages don't know what @subscription is

Comment: check if you have `resources :subscriptions` line in `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: yes that was put there by the scaffold

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23168/discussion-between-wasi-and-railsy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to simply change:

```
<%= form_for @subscription ...
```

To:

```
<%= form_for Subscription.new ...
```

And, like has already been noted, I doubt you need the url options.